# Bootstrap 4: add a "scroll to first invalid field" to a don't "Submit" if invalid script

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I am using `Bootstrap 4` and i am stopping form submission if any of the fields are invalid with the below script.
I am trying to figure out (with no success so far) what code do i need to add after the "**`event.stopPropagation();`**" in order to make the form scroll to the first invalid field that was found.
Appreciate your help, thanks.

Form:

```
<form class="needs-validation" novalidate action="search.php" id="firstform" method="post" >
```

Prevent submission if invalid:

```
  <script>
// Example starter JavaScript for disabling form submissions if there are invalid fields
(function() {
  'use strict';
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
    var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
    // Loop over them and prevent submission
    var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
      form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagation();
        }
        form.classList.add('was-validated');
      }, false);
    });
  }, false);
})();
</script>
```

Found the below code but couldn't find a way to embed it into the "disabling form submissions" script or use it as a standalone script:

```
$("#firstform").validate({
    focusInvalid: false,
    invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {

        if (!validator.numberOfInvalids())
            return;

        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(validator.errorList[0].element).offset().top
        }, 2000);

    }
});
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use the `input.form-control:invalid` pseudo selector that is added to the elements you’ll see the `:invalid` and `:valid` styles applied to your form controls.

Although using custom validation you have to look for a lot of things that this [**`article`**](https://css-tricks.com/form-validation-part-2-constraint-validation-api-javascript/) can cover up for you.

We will use the above selector `document.querySelectorAll("input.form-control:invalid");` to get all the error fields list and scroll to the first error element in the form in case there are multiple errors.

See a demo below.

```js
// Example starter JavaScript for disabling form submissions if there are invalid fields
(function() {
  'use strict';
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
    var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
    // Loop over them and prevent submission
    var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
      form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {

        if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagation();

          var errorElements = document.querySelectorAll(
            "input.form-control:invalid");
          errorElements.forEach(function(element) {
            element.parentNode.childNodes.forEach(function(node) {
              if (node.className == 'valid-feedback') {
                node.className = 'invalid-feedback';
                node.innerText =
                  'Please choose a Gender';
              }
            });
          });
          $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(errorElements[0]).offset().top
          }, 2000);
        }
        form.classList.add('was-validated');
      }, false);
    });
  }, false);
})();
```

```css
input[type=text],
input[type=email],
input[type=number],
textarea,
fieldset {
  /* required to properly style form 
   elements on WebKit based browsers */
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 90%;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<form class="needs-validation" novalidate>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
      <label for="gender">Male</label>
      <input id="gender_male" type="radio" name="gender" class="form-control col-sm-2" required>
      <label for="gender">Female</label>
      <input id="gender_female" type="radio" name="gender" class="form-control col-sm-2">
      <label for="gender">Other</label>
      <input id="gender_other" type="radio" name="gender" class="form-control col-sm-2">

      <div class="valid-feedback">
        Looks good!
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
      <label for="validationCustom01">First name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom01" placeholder="First name" value="Mark" required>
      <div class="valid-feedback">
        Looks good!
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
      <label for="validationCustom02">Last name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom02" placeholder="Last name" value="Otto" required>
      <div class="valid-feedback">
        Looks good!
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
      <label for="validationCustomUsername">Username</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroupPrepend">@</span>
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustomUsername" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="inputGroupPrepend" required>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
          Please choose a username.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
      <label for="validationCustom03">City</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom03" placeholder="City" required>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">
        Please provide a valid city.
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
      <label for="validationCustom04">State</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom04" placeholder="State" required>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">
        Please provide a valid state.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
      <label for="validationCustom05">Zip</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom05" placeholder="Zip" required>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">
        Please provide a valid zip.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
      <label for="validationCustom05">Zip</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom05" placeholder="Zip" required>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">
        Please provide a valid zip.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="invalidCheck" required>
      <label class="form-check-label" for="invalidCheck">
                Agree to terms and conditions
            </label>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">
        You must agree before submitting.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit form</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you! , worked like a charm. i just added "-100" after the ".top" to overcome the fixed navbar i have and reduced the 2000msec to 1000msec, it's working great.

Comment: @Mark.D glad it worked for you , you can adjust it according to your needs

Comment: i have a radio button group with 2 buttons that's empty when you enter the form and at least one is "required" , when using the "var errorElements = document.querySelectorAll("input.form-control:invalid");" and the only invalid is the radio button group it does not catch it , any idea why ? , in case there is an additional invalid field it does show the radio as invalid together with the previous invalid inputs.

Comment: you have to use the `form-control` class on the input and you need to tweak the javascript too i have updated the answer run the snippet to see the radio button group being prompted to be selected even if it is the only input. @Mark.D

Comment: Thank you, I've used `form-check-input` class for the radio buttons because of the bootstrap 4 documentation, once i changed to `form-control` as you suggested the previous javascript worked fine with no tweak. I can't tell the difference between using the `form-control` or `form-check-input` classes. should i notice something ? . @Muhammad

Comment: does the error messages show up for the radio button group without updating the javascript? I am not sure it will show you, as the class `valid-feedback` isn't changed too `invalid-feedback` and hence does not show up at least not in chrome. can you confirm? @Mark.D

Comment: Yes, they show up for the radio button group with the previous tweak you did, i just changed the `form-check-input' to `form-control` on the radio buttons and it worked. Not sure what is the actual difference between the 2 classes. If it helps, i placed `required` and `invalid-feedback` only on one of them, the last one. @Muhammad

Answer (score 2):

If you are using jQuery and only supporting modern browsers (which is likely if you're using Bootstrap 4), you can use the following code to validate the form and scroll to the field with an error:

```
$('form#contact').submit(function(e) {
    var form = $(this);

    // HTML5 validility checker
    if (form[0].checkValidity() === false) {
        // not valid
        form.addClass('was-validated');
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $('.was-validated .form-control:invalid').first().offset().top - 50},'slow');
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        return;
    }
    // valid, do something else ...
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add these two lines

```
var errorElements = document.querySelectorAll(".form-control:invalid");
$(errorElements[0]).focus();
```

after

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

Putting focus to the first invalid field will automatically scroll the page to that position i
in most of the browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Sergej, this worked great!

I modified it as below so that checkboxes/radio buttons and drop-down menus are also detected.

```
var errorElements = document.querySelectorAll(".form-control:invalid, .form-check-input:invalid, .form-select:invalid");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$( "input[type=submit]" ).click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    //  console.log("test")
    var errorElements = document.querySelectorAll(".input-validation-error");
  for (let index = 0; index < errorElements.length; index++) {
      const element = errorElements[index];
    //  console.log(element);
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(errorElements[0]).focus().offset().top - 25
      }, 1000);      
      return false;
  }
});
```