# bootstrap custom validation is not showing up specific field on submission of the form

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I want to know how to make the bootstrap custom validation also show the specific field where the form is not filled.

You can observe the normal form shows or goes to the specific field which is not filled when the form is submitted

where bootstrap custom validation doesn't do that.

**This is the code with out bootstrap custom validation**

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<form>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
      <label for="validationDefault01">First name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationDefault01" placeholder="First name" value="Mark" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
      <label for="validationDefault02">Last name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationDefault02" placeholder="Last name" value="Otto" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
      <label for="validationDefaultUsername">Username</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroupPrepend2">@</span>
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationDefaultUsername" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="inputGroupPrepend2" required>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
      <label for="validationDefault03">City</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationDefault03" placeholder="City" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
      <label for="validationDefault04">State</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationDefault04" placeholder="State" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
      <label for="validationDefault05">Zip</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationDefault05" placeholder="Zip" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="invalidCheck2" required>
      <label class="form-check-label" for="invalidCheck2">
        Agree to terms and conditions
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit form</button>
</form>
```

**This is the bootstrap validation**

```js
// Example starter JavaScript for disabling form submissions if there are invalid fields
(function() {
  'use strict';
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
    var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
    // Loop over them and prevent submission
    var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
      form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagation();
        }
        form.classList.add('was-validated');
      }, false);
    });
  }, false);
})();
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <form class="needs-validation" novalidate>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
        <label for="validationCustom01">First name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom01" placeholder="First name" value="Mark" required>
        <div class="valid-feedback">
          Looks good!
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
        <label for="validationCustom02">Last name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom02" placeholder="Last name" value="Otto" required>
        <div class="valid-feedback">
          Looks good!
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
        <label for="validationCustomUsername">Username</label>
        <div class="input-group">
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroupPrepend">@</span>
          </div>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustomUsername" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="inputGroupPrepend" required>
          <div class="invalid-feedback">
            Please choose a username.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
        <label for="validationCustom03">City</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom03" placeholder="City" required>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
          Please provide a valid city.
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
        <label for="validationCustom04">State</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom04" placeholder="State" required>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
          Please provide a valid state.
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
        <label for="validationCustom05">Zip</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom05" placeholder="Zip" required>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
          Please provide a valid zip.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="invalidCheck" required>
        <label class="form-check-label" for="invalidCheck">
        Agree to terms and conditions
      </label>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
          You must agree before submitting.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit form</button>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: use jQuery validate https://jqueryvalidation.org/ its way better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated the code by using some JavaScript code.

And it's working. :)

```js
// Example starter JavaScript for disabling form submissions if there are invalid fields
(function() {
  'use strict';
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
    var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
    // Loop over them and prevent submission
    var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
      form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagation();
          var invalidOptions = document.querySelectorAll(
            ".form-control:invalid");
          invalidOptions.forEach(function(element) {
            element.parentNode.childNodes.forEach(function(node) {
              if (node.className == 'valid-feedback') {
                node.className = 'invalid-feedback';
                node.innerText =
                  'Please choose a Gender';
              }
            });
          });
          $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(invalidOptions[0]).offset().top
          }, 2000);
        }
        form.classList.add('was-validated');
      }, false);
    });
  }, false);
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <form class="needs-validation" novalidate>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
        <label for="validationCustom01">First name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom01" placeholder="First name" value="Mark" required>
        <div class="valid-feedback">
          Looks good!
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
        <label for="validationCustom02">Last name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom02" placeholder="Last name" value="Otto" required>
        <div class="valid-feedback">
          Looks good!
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
        <label for="validationCustomUsername">Username</label>
        <div class="input-group">
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroupPrepend">@</span>
          </div>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustomUsername" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="inputGroupPrepend" required>
          <div class="invalid-feedback">
            Please choose a username.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
        <label for="validationCustom03">City</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom03" placeholder="City" required>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
          Please provide a valid city.
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
        <label for="validationCustom04">State</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom04" placeholder="State" required>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
          Please provide a valid state.
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
        <label for="validationCustom05">Zip</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom05" placeholder="Zip" required>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
          Please provide a valid zip.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="invalidCheck" required>
        <label class="form-check-label" for="invalidCheck">
        Agree to terms and conditions
      </label>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
          You must agree before submitting.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit form</button>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you remove `novalidate=""` from `<form class="needs-validation was-validated" novalidate="">` you get the same result as without Bootstrap validation.

`novalidate` prevents the browser to validate the form so you can apply the custom behaviour of Bootstrap.

If you want to add scroll to id after the validation I suppose you have to do by yourself or check if there is such config in the library you are using.

Comment: i want both  custom validation with red border and i want to go for specific element which is not filled.

Comment: if we remove `novalidate` it's behaving as default validation . i want to go for specific filed in custom validation also..@iGian

Comment: As in my post, if there is no configuration setting you need to add custom javascript. Check if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50319997/5239030) is good for you.