# How to scroll to first invalid field in bootstrap on submit if invalid fields exist

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I tried to achieve this by 3 different ways but none seemed to work

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
// Example starter JavaScript for disabling form submissions if there are invalid fields
    (function() {
    'use strict';
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
        var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
        // Loop over them and prevent submission
        var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
        form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
            if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
                event.preventDefault();
                event.stopPropagation();
                
                // method 1
                // window.scrollTo({top: 0, behavior: 'smooth'});

                // method 2
                // window.scrollTo(0, 0);
                
                // method 3
                // $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: "2000" });
            }
            form.classList.add('was-validated');
        }, false);
        });
    }, false);
    })();

    function recaptchaCallback() {
        $('#contact-submit').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
</script>
```

This is the code for my form:

```
<form action="" method="POST" class="needs-validation d-flex justify-content-center padding-t-56 padding-b-56" data-abide novalidate>
    <div class="application-body">
        <div class="tab d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-between padding-t-16 padding-x-16 margin-b-56">
            <h3 class=" margin-t-0 col-12">Contact details</h3>
            
            <div class="col-12 col-md-5">
                <!-- Full name -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="" for="applicantName" id="applicantNameLabel">Applicant’s or nominee’s full name*</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="applicantName" name="applicantName" placeholder="Please enter your full name." aria-labelledby="applicantNameLabel" <?php if ( isset( $applicantName ) ) echo 'value="'.$applicantName.'"'; ?> required/>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">Please enter your name.</div>
                </div>
                <!-- email -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="" for="applicantEmail" id="applicantEmailLabel">Applicant’s or nominee’s email*</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="applicantEmail" name="applicantEmail" 
                    pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$" required placeholder="Please enter your email." aria-labelledby="applicantEmailLabel" <?php if ( isset( $applicantEmail ) ) echo 'value="'.$applicantEmail.'"'; ?>/>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">Please enter a valid email address.</div>
                </div>
                <!-- phone number ^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$ / [0-9]{10} -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="" for="applicantPhone" id="applicantPhoneLabel">Applicant’s or nominee’s phone number*</label>
                    <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="applicantPhone" pattern="^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$" name="applicantPhone" placeholder="Please enter your phone number." aria-labelledby="applicantPhoneLabel" required <?php if ( isset( $applicantPhone ) ) echo 'value="'.$applicantPhone.'"'; ?>/>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">Please enter a valid phone number, including area code. Enter digits only. Try this format: xxx-xxx-xxxx</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-md-5">
                <!-- address -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="" for="address" id="addressLabel">Applicant’s or nominee’s address</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address" name="address" placeholder="Please enter your address." aria-labelledby="addressLabel" <?php if ( isset( $address ) ) echo 'value="'.$address.'"'; ?> />
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">Please enter your address.</div>
                </div>
                <!-- city -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="" for="city" id="cityLabel">Applicant’s or nominee’s city*<span id="req"></span></label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="city" name="city" placeholder="Please enter your city." aria-labelledby="cityLabel" required <?php if ( isset( $city ) ) echo 'value="'.$city.'"'; ?> />
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">Please enter your city.</div>
                </div>
                <!-- province -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="" for="province" id="provinceLabel">Applicant’s or nominee’s province</label>
                    <select class="custom-select" id="province" name="province" aria-labelledby="provinceLabel">
                        <option value="AB" <?php if ( isset( $province ) && $province == 'AB' ) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Alberta</option>
                        <option value="BC" <?php if ( isset( $province ) && $province == 'BC' ) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>British Columbia</option>
                        <option value="MB" <?php if ( isset( $province ) && $province == 'MB' ) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Manitoba</option>
                        <option value="NB" <?php if ( isset( $province ) && $province == 'NB' ) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>New Brunswick</option>
                        <option value="NL" <?php if ( isset( $province ) && $province == 'NL' ) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Newfoundland and Labrador</option>
                        <option value="NS" <?php if ( isset( $province ) && $province == 'NS' ) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Nova Scotia</option>
                        <option value="ON" <?php if ( isset( $province ) && $province == 'ON' ) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Ontario</option>
                        <option value="PE" <?php if ( isset( $province ) && $province == 'PE' ) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Prince Edward Island</option>
                        <option value="QC" <?php if ( isset( $province ) && $province == 'QC' ) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Quebec</option>
                        <option value="SK" <?php if ( isset( $province ) && $province == 'SK' ) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Saskatchewan</option>
                        <option value="NT" <?php if ( isset( $province ) && $province == 'NT' ) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Northwest Territories</option>
                        <option value="NU" <?php if ( isset( $province ) && $province == 'NU' ) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Nunavut</option>
                        <option value="YT" <?php if ( isset( $province ) && $province == 'YT' ) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Yukon</option>
                    </select>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        Select a province.
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- postal code -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="" for="postalCode" id="postalCodeLabel">Applicant’s or nominee’s postal code</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="postalCode" name="postalCode" placeholder="Please enter your postal code." aria-labelledby="postalCodeLabel" <?php if ( isset( $postal_code ) ) echo 'value="'.$postal_code.'"'; ?> />
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">Please enter your postal code.</div>
                </div>
            </div>          
        </div>
        <div class="col col-12 tr-faq">
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col margin-t-56 margin-b-32 padding-x-16">
            <h5>If you’re nominating someone else:</h5>
            <!-- Full name -->
            <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="" for="nominatorName" id="nominatorNameLabel">Your full name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nominatorName" name="nominatorName" placeholder="Please enter your full name." aria-labelledby="nominatorNameLabel" <?php if ( isset( $nominatorName ) ) echo 'value="'.$nominatorName.'"'; ?>/>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">Please enter your name</div>
                </div>
                <!-- email -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="" for="nominatorEmail" id="nominatorEmailLabel">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="nominatorEmail" name="nominatorEmail" 
                    pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$" placeholder="Please enter your email." aria-labelledby="nominatorEmailLabel" <?php if ( isset( $nominatorEmail ) ) echo 'value="'.$nominatorEmail.'"'; ?>/>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">Please enter a valid email address.</div>
                </div>
                <!-- phone number -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="" for="nominatorPhone" id="nominatorPhoneLabel">Phone number</label>
                    <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="nominatorPhone" pattern="[0-9]{10}" name="nominatorPhone" placeholder="Please enter your phone number." aria-labelledby="nominatorPhoneLabel" <?php if ( isset( $nominatorPhone ) ) echo 'value="'.$nominatorPhone.'"'; ?>/>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">Please enter a valid phone number, including area code. Enter digits only.</div>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-12 tr-faq">
        </div>
        <!-- Why you are a reason of face of wellness -->
        <div class="tab flex-column margin-t-56 margin-b-32 padding-x-16">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="" for="details" id="detailsLabel">The reason why you or your nominee is a face of wellness*:</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" id="details" name="details" placeholder="Tell us why you or your nominee is a face of wellness." aria-labelledby="detailsLabel" required><?php if ( isset( $details ) ) echo $details; ?></textarea>
                <div class="invalid-feedback">Please tell us why you or your nominee is a face of wellness.</div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group captcha-field">
                <h4 class="margin-t-48 margin-b-0">Security check</h4>
                <p>Protecting your information is our number one priority. Before we send can submit your question to our team, we just need to check that you are not a robot. Click the checkbox on the reCAPTCHA form below to confirm you are human and we will be in touch shortly.</p>
                <div class="g-recaptcha" data-callback="recaptchaCallback" data-sitekey="<?php echo $sitekey; ?>">              </div>
                <?php 
                if ($captchaError )  {

                    echo '<div class="captchaError">'.$captchaError.'</div>';

                } // if ( !empty( $errors ) )
                //   if ($recaptchaError )  {

                //     echo '<div class="captchaError">'.$recaptchaError.'</div>';

                // }
                ?>
            </div>
            
            <p class="padding-r-24">You will receive a confirmation message to the email you provided in your application shortly. To complete your application, please respond to the email with any relevant imagery or video that supports your submission (if applicable).</p>
            
            <input type="submit" name="submitted" class="btn primary-btn contact-submit-button" id="contact-submit" aria-labelledby="submit button" disabled>
        <!--<div style="overflow:auto;">
            <div style="float:right;">
                <button type="button" id="prevBtn" class="btn secondary-btn" onclick="nextPrev(-1)">Previous</button>
                <button type="button" id="nextBtn" class="btn secondary-btn" onclick="nextPrev(1)">Next</button>
                
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="text-align:center;margin-top:40px;">
            <span class="step"></span>
            <span class="step"></span>
             <span class="step"></span>
            <span class="step"></span>
        </div> -->
    </div>
    
</form>
```

I also tried to implement this:[Bootstrap 4: add a "scroll to first invalid field" to a don't "Submit" if invalid script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50319538/bootstrap-4-add-a-scroll-to-first-invalid-field-to-a-dont-submit-if-invali) in my code and that didn't work either.

If anyone can point me in the right direction, it'd be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried [`scrollIntoView()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)?

Comment: I did now but it didnt work either

Answer (score 0):

You posted the html code rather than the rendered html so I removed all your php markup and the submit button for the sake of the example.

But as you can see the call to `scrollIntoView()` does work, at least here.  I do not know why it fails for you unless you are acting on an element that it cannot find or has maybe been "name mangled" on render.

#### Something else to consider

Take into account the postback.

If you are validating client side. then be sure you do not postback until all fields pass validation. In this case scrollIntoView should be fine.

If any validation takes place on the server, then you'll have to wait until the page renders and make the failed field id available to your scrollIntoView function on load

#### Modified to simulate postback operations

Note addition of onload handler to body tag.  So it works like this:

1. User hits submit
2. Validation checks occur on server
3. On first failure you set the hidden field value
4. Page renders and `onload` the function `checkValidation` looks at the hidden field

```js
function checkValidation() {
  let elemID = document.getElementById("_FAILED_VALIDATION").value;

  if (elemID !== "NONE") {
    let options = {
      behavior: "smooth",
      block: "center"
    }

    document
      .getElementById(elemID)
      .scrollIntoView(options);
  }
}
```

```css
button#Example {
  background-color: pink;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body onload="checkValidation()">
  <!-- <button id="Example" type=button onclick="foo(event)">Scroll Other Nominee Email Into View</button> -->


  <!-- hidden field is either "NONE" or the id of the field that failed validation -->
  <input type="hidden" id="_FAILED_VALIDATION" value="nominatorEmail">




  <form action="" class="needs-validation d-flex justify-content-center padding-t-56 padding-b-56" data-abide novalidate>
    <div class="application-body">
      <div class="tab d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-between padding-t-16 padding-x-16 margin-b-56">
        <h3 class=" margin-t-0 col-12">Contact details</h3>

        <div class="col-12 col-md-5">
          <!-- Full name -->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="" for="applicantName" id="applicantNameLabel">Applicant’s or nominee’s full name*</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="applicantName" name="applicantName" placeholder="Please enter your full name." aria-labelledby="applicantNameLabel" required/>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">Please enter your name.</div>
          </div>
          <!-- email -->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="" for="applicantEmail" id="applicantEmailLabel">Applicant’s or nominee’s email*</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="applicantEmail" name="applicantEmail" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$" required placeholder="Please enter your email." aria-labelledby="applicantEmailLabel" />
            <div class="invalid-feedback">Please enter a valid email address.</div>
          </div>
          <!-- phone number ^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$ / [0-9]{10} -->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="" for="applicantPhone" id="applicantPhoneLabel">Applicant’s or nominee’s phone number*</label>
            <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="applicantPhone" pattern="^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$" name="applicantPhone" placeholder="Please enter your phone number." aria-labelledby="applicantPhoneLabel" required />
            <div class="invalid-feedback">Please enter a valid phone number, including area code. Enter digits only. Try this format: xxx-xxx-xxxx</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-5">
          <!-- address -->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="" for="address" id="addressLabel">Applicant’s or nominee’s address</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address" name="address" placeholder="Please enter your address." aria-labelledby="addressLabel" />
            <div class="invalid-feedback">Please enter your address.</div>
          </div>
          <!-- city -->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="" for="city" id="cityLabel">Applicant’s or nominee’s city*<span id="req"></span></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="city" name="city" placeholder="Please enter your city." aria-labelledby="cityLabel" required />
            <div class="invalid-feedback">Please enter your city.</div>
          </div>
          <!-- province -->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="" for="province" id="provinceLabel">Applicant’s or nominee’s province</label>
            <select class="custom-select" id="province" name="province" aria-labelledby="provinceLabel">
              <option value="AB">Alberta</option>
              <option value="BC">British Columbia</option>
              <option value="MB">Manitoba</option>
              <option value="NB">New Brunswick</option>
              <option value="NL">Newfoundland and Labrador</option>
              <option value="NS">Nova Scotia</option>
              <option value="ON">Ontario</option>
              <option value="PE">Prince Edward Island</option>
              <option value="QC">Quebec</option>
              <option value="SK">Saskatchewan</option>
              <option value="NT">Northwest Territories</option>
              <option value="NU">Nunavut</option>
              <option value="YT">Yukon</option>
            </select>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
              Select a province.
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- postal code -->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="" for="postalCode" id="postalCodeLabel">Applicant’s or nominee’s postal code</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="postalCode" name="postalCode" placeholder="Please enter your postal code." aria-labelledby="postalCodeLabel" />
            <div class="invalid-feedback">Please enter your postal code.</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col col-12 tr-faq">
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col margin-t-56 margin-b-32 padding-x-16">
        <h5>If you’re nominating someone else:</h5>
        <!-- Full name -->
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="" for="nominatorName" id="nominatorNameLabel">Your full name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nominatorName" name="nominatorName" placeholder="Please enter your full name." aria-labelledby="nominatorNameLabel" />
          <div class="invalid-feedback">Please enter your name</div>
        </div>
        <!-- email -->
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="" for="nominatorEmail" id="nominatorEmailLabel">Email</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="nominatorEmail" name="nominatorEmail" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$" placeholder="Please enter your email." aria-labelledby="nominatorEmailLabel" />
          <div class="invalid-feedback">Please enter a valid email address.</div>
        </div>
        <!-- phone number -->
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="" for="nominatorPhone" id="nominatorPhoneLabel">Phone number</label>
          <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="nominatorPhone" pattern="[0-9]{10}" name="nominatorPhone" placeholder="Please enter your phone number." aria-labelledby="nominatorPhoneLabel" />
          <div class="invalid-feedback">Please enter a valid phone number, including area code. Enter digits only.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col col-12 tr-faq">
      </div>
      <!-- Why you are a reason of face of wellness -->
      <div class="tab flex-column margin-t-56 margin-b-32 padding-x-16">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="" for="details" id="detailsLabel">The reason why you or your nominee is a face of wellness*:</label>
          <textarea class="form-control" id="details" name="details" placeholder="Tell us why you or your nominee is a face of wellness." aria-labelledby="detailsLabel" required></textarea>
          <div class="invalid-feedback">Please tell us why you or your nominee is a face of wellness.</div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group captcha-field">
          <h4 class="margin-t-48 margin-b-0">Security check</h4>
          <p>Protecting your information is our number one priority. Before we send can submit your question to our team, we just need to check that you are not a robot. Click the checkbox on the reCAPTCHA form below to confirm you are human and we will
            be in touch shortly.</p>
          <div class="g-recaptcha" data-callback="recaptchaCallback" data-sitekey=""> </div>

        </div>

        <p class="padding-r-24">You will receive a confirmation message to the email you provided in your application shortly. To complete your application, please respond to the email with any relevant imagery or video that supports your submission (if applicable).</p>

      </div>

  </form>

  <body>
```

Comment: I want to scroll to the invalid field only after the user hits submit and I'm unclear on your approach. What I understood is, you added an onclick event on the button and it worked which it would but I don't want that functionality.

Comment: that was just to demonstrate the function `scrollIntoView()`.  If you want this to work after postback then one option is to set a hidden field element with the ID of the field that failed.  I'll modify my example.

Comment: I tried this and what you explained makes sense but I am unable to make it work for "submit". Also, if I go by your approach, would it not scroll every time regardless if the form passed the validation or not?

Comment: As written, if the value of the hidden field is "NONE" then no, it won't scroll.  This value can be whatever you prefer, and should be the default.  As for "Submit" this will cause a postback where I assume you are doing validation.  Your code should know which fields, if any, fail and on first failure set the hidden field to the id string of the failed input.

Comment: I tweeked the code a little by changing the ID to classname and it didn't work. It didn't work before either. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: well...`scrollIntoView()` works, all the methods I've shown work here in the snippet.  If it's not working for you it has to be something you're overlooking.  What browser and version are you using? Is javascript enabled on your web page? When changing the id to classname be sure to use `document.querySelector()` instead of `document.getElementById()`  Personally I'd use the ID as IDs are unique. Using classnames means you now have to manage the uniqueness.

Comment: Also, monitor the page as it loads by using the browser devtools.  Make sure there aren't any JS exceptions shown in the console before the page finishes loading.